# Ruby on Rails: User_id and category_id is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Following to my last question ([Ruby on Rails: Relation between two models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32808121/ruby-on-rails-relation-between-two-models)) I've got some new problems:

I am using Devise and there you can enter a user name beside email and so on. This works and the name gets saved to the db.

Now I'm trying to call that user name on a specific "show" page, to illustrate who created the request:

```
<%= @request.user.name if @request.user %>
```

Furthermore I want only the specific user who created the request to be able to delete and edit:

```
<% if current_user && @request.user == current_user %>
   <%= link_to edit_request_path(@request), class: "btn btn-default" do %>
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
       Edit
   <% end %>
   <%= link_to @request, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Bist du sicher?' }, class: "btn btn-default" do %>
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
       Löschen
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

For that I've set up a class in my requests_controller.rb:

```
def correct_user
  @request = current_user.requests.find_by(id: params[:id])
  redirect_to requests_path, alert: 'Keine Berechtigung bearbeiten' if @request.nil?
end
```

But neither the username shows up nor the delete and edit buttons :(

Here is the request.rb:

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :category
 belongs_to :user
 validates :description, presence: true, length: { maximum: 500 }
 validates :title, presence: true
 validates :budget, presence: true
 validates :category, presence: true
end
```

and the user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
         has_many :requests
         validates :name, presence: true
end
```

I did this migration to add the UserID to Requests model so I can call the user through @request.user.name:

```
class AddUserIdToRequests < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :requests, :user_id, :integer
  end
end
```

excerpt of my request_controller.rb:

```
class RequestsController < ApplicationController
before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

private
    def set_request
      @request = Request.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @request = current_user.requests.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to requests_path, alert: 'Keine Berechtigung bearbeiten' if @request.nil?
    end

    def request_params
      params.require(:request).permit(:title, :description, :tags, :budget, :name)
    end
```

Comment: Can you show your models? How is your User model relationship with Request model?

Comment: @Gerep thx for the hint. Done!

Comment: You said that you have create the method `correct_user` but I can't see where you are calling it, can you please add your request controller?

Comment: @Gerep sorry for the late response (was ill). I edited the relevant parts of my request_controller.rb in.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the method `correct_user` is called before you render the view. On second note, make sure the `request` object has a `user` associated with it.(ie, @request.user should not be nil)

Also the way you compare the logged in user and owner is wrong at below line

```
<% if current_user && @request.user == current_user %>
```

It should be something like this

```
<% if current_user && @request.user.id == current_user.id %>
```

If you compare objects, they wont be same. Please compare `id`

Comment: That does not work. I've used the "<% if current_user && @request.user == current_user %>" before.. so it should work. I guess that the relation between the user and the request table isn't working (on the DB site..). How can I check if the foreign keys and so on are correct?